# Unit testing using library 'unittest' in Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, unit-testing, python-3.6, python-unittest

I need to write test cases using unit test in Python for testing circle creation.

> Define a class Circle with method init which initializes a circle with
> attribute radius, having following restrictions.
>
> 1. radius must be numeric value, if not raise type error with error message "radius must be number".
> 2. radius must be between 0 to 1000 inclusive on both sides, if not raise the value error with error message "radius must be between 0 and
>    1000 inclusive"
> 3. Define a class method area and circumference which must return values rounded off to 2 decimals.
>
> Complete the definition of class TestingCircleCircumference which
> tests the behaviour of circumference  method as specification below.
>
> Define the test method test_circlecircum_with_random_numerical_radius
> which creates circle c1 with radius 2.5 and check if its computed
> circumference match the value 15.71
>
> Define the test method test_circlecircum_with__min_radius which
> creates circle c2 with radius 0 and check if its computed
> circumference match the value 0
>
> Define the test method test_circlecircum_with_max_radius  which
> creates circle c3 with radius 1000 and check if its computed
> circumference match the value 6283.19

My code is:

```
import inspect
import re
import unittest
import math

class Circle:

    def __init__(self, radius):

        try:
            if not isinstance(radius, (int, float)):
                raise TypeError
            elif 1000 >= radius >= 0:
                self.radius=radius
            else:
                raise ValueError
        except ValueError:
            raise ValueError("radius must be between 0 and 1000 inclusive")
        except TypeError:
            raise TypeError("radius must be a number")

def area(self):

    y = math.pi*(self.radius**2)
    return round(y, 2)

def circumference(self):

    x = math.pi*2*self.radius
    return round(x, 2)

class TestCircleArea(unittest.TestCase):

    def test_circlearea_with_random_numeric_radius(self):

        c1 = Circle(2.5)
        self.assertEqual(c1.area(), 19.63)


    def test_circlearea_with_min_radius(self):

        c2 = Circle(0)
        self.assertEqual(c2.area(), 0)

    def test_circlearea_with_max_radius(self):

        c3 = Circle(1000.1)
        self.assertEqual(c3.area(), 3141592.65)
```

The below code is generated by the system and I can't edit it. This code is from [HackerRank](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HackerRank).

```
if __name__ == '__main__':

    fptr = open('output.txt', 'w')

    runner = unittest.TextTestRunner(fptr)

    unittest.main(testRunner=runner, exit=False)

    fptr.close()

    with open('output.txt') as fp:
        output_lines = fp.readlines()


    pass_count = [len(re.findall(r'\.', line)) for line in output_lines if line.startswith('.')
                     and line.endswith('.\n')]

    pass_count = pass_count[0]

    print(str(pass_count))

    doc1 = inspect.getsource(TestCircleArea.test_circlearea_with_random_numeric_radius)
    doc2 = inspect.getsource(TestCircleArea.test_circlearea_with_min_radius)
    doc3 = inspect.getsource(TestCircleArea.test_circlearea_with_max_radius)

    assert1_count = len(re.findall(r'assertEqual', doc1))

    print(str(assert1_count))

    assert1_count = len(re.findall(r'assertEqual', doc2))

    print(str(assert1_count))

    assert1_count = len(re.findall(r'assertEqual', doc3))

    print(str(assert1_count))
```

The error I am getting is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 75, in <module>
    pass_count = pass_count[0]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Comment: It's unrelated to your problem, but note that your error handling in `__init__` doesn't really make sense. Why not include the message when you *first* throw the errors, rather than catching them *then* throwing a new error of the same class but with a message? Imagine you had a second reason for a `ValueError`, e.g. you wanted to send a different message for a negative number than for a number greater than 1,000; how would you distinguish between the two in the `except` block?

Comment: As to your specific problem, if `pass_count[0]` is an `IndexError`, then `pass_count` is empty. It's unclear why you're doing such a complicated thing for your tests, but you should check what's actually in `output.txt`.

Comment: `pass_count` is empty as it  is not able to find any output lines, in your output.txt, as per the condition defined by you.

Comment: There are no lines in `output.txt` starting with `'.'`.

Comment: How is exact match of floating point numbers supposed to work here?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve the given problem using the below class and *testing class methods*.

```
class Circle:
    
    def __init__(self, radius):
        # Define the initialization method below
        self.radius = radius
        if not isinstance(self.radius, (int, float)):
            raise TypeError("radius must be a number")
        elif self.radius < 0 or self.radius > 1000:
            raise ValueError("radius must be between 0 and 1000 inclusive")
        else:
            pass
        
    def area(self):
        # Define the area functionality below
        return round(math.pi*(self.radius**2), 2)
               
    def circumference(self):
        # Define the circumference functionality below
        return round(2*math.pi*self.radius, 2)
        
class TestCircleCircumference(unittest.TestCase):
    
    def test_circlecircum_with_random_numeric_radius(self):
        # Define a circle 'c1' with radius 2.5 and check if 
        # its circumference is 15.71
        c1 = Circle(2.5)
        self.assertEqual(c1.circumference(), 15.71)

        
    def test_circlecircum_with_min_radius(self):
        # Define a circle 'c2' with radius 0 and check if 
        # it's circumference is 0.
        c2 = Circle(0)
        self.assertEqual(c2.circumference(),0)
                
    def test_circlecircum_with_max_radius(self):
        # Define a circle 'c3' with radius 1000 and check if 
        # it's circumference is 6283.19.
        c3 = Circle(1000)
        self.assertEqual(c3.circumference(),6283.19)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just modify the code as follows:

1. Remove/delete the passcount line
2. Directly assign the value i.e. total number of tests to be performed.
3. Enjoy, no more errors.

This is just to skip the default thing which keeps irritating.

Answer (score 0):

You getting the error because the value of `c3` is not getting initialized due to the conditions you are putting in your `__init__` method.

Please remove it if you want to initialize it to 1000.1:

```
class Circle:
    
    def __init__(self, radius):
        self.radius = radius

    def area(self):
        return round((math.pi*(self.radius)**2), 2)
        
               
    def circumference(self):
        return round((math.pi*(self.radius)*2), 2)
```

One more thing: the area of c3 is 3142221.0, not the value you are testing. Please print and check it once.

```
class TestCircleArea(unittest.TestCase):
    
    def test_circlearea_with_random_numeric_radius(self):
        c1 = Circle(2.5)
        self.assertEqual(c1.area(), 19.63)
        
    def test_circlearea_with_min_radius(self):
        c2 = Circle(0)
        self.assertEqual(c2.area(), 0.0)

    def test_circlearea_with_max_radius(self):
        c3 = Circle(1000.1)
        #print(c3.area())
        self.assertEqual(c3.area(), 3142221.0)
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
def test_circlearea_with_max_radius(self):
    c3 = Circle(1000)
    #print(c3.area())
    self.assertEqual(c3.area(), 3141592.65)
```

I verified this works fine. The number is 1000, not 1000.1. It seems like issue with input suggestion.

Comment: How does exact match of floating point numbers work here?

Answer (score 0):

class Circle:

```
def __init__(self, radius):
  
    self.radius = 0
    if not isinstance(radius,(int,float)):
        raise TypeError("radius must be a number")
    elif radius < 0 or radius > 1000:
        raise ValueError("radius must be between 0 and 1000 inclusive")
    else:
        self.radius = radius
    
def area(self):
    
    return round(math.pi*(self.radius**2),2) 
           
def circumference(self):
 
    return round((math.pi*self.radius*2),2)
```

class TestCircleArea(unittest.TestCase):

```
def test_circlearea_with_random_numeric_radius(self):
    
    c1 = Circle(2.5)
    self.assertEqual(c1.area(), 19.63)
    
def test_circlearea_with_min_radius(self):
    
    c2 = Circle(0)
    self.assertEqual(c2.area(), 0)
    
def test_circlearea_with_max_radius(self):
    
    c3 = Circle(1000)
    self.assertEqual(c3.area(), 3141592.65)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to [this GitHub file](https://github.com/kunupat/python-unit-test/blob/master/unit_test_example_3.py)

or

```py
# Define below the class 'Circle' and it's methods.
class Circle:
    
    def __init__(self, radius):
        # Define the initialization method below
        pattern = re.compile("^\\-?[0-9]")
        if(pattern.match(str(radius))):
            if(radius >= 0 and radius <= 1000):
                self.radius = radius
            else:
                raise ValueError("radius must be between 0 and 1000 inclusive")
        else:
            raise TypeError("radius must be a number")
        
        
    def area(self):
        # Define the area functionality below
        return round(((self.radius ** 2) * math.pi),2)

    def circumference(self):
        # Define the circumference functionality below
        return round((self.radius * 2 * math.pi),2)
        
class TestCircleCircumference(unittest.TestCase):
    
    def test_circlecircum_with_random_numeric_radius(self):
        # Define a circle 'c1' with radius 2.5 and check if 
        # it's circumference is 15.71
        c1= Circle(2.5)
        self.assertEqual(c1.circumference(), 15.71)
        
    def test_circlecircum_with_min_radius(self):
        # Define a circle 'c2' with radius 0 and check if 
        # it's circumference is 0.
        c2= Circle(0)
        self.assertEqual(c2.circumference(), 0)
        
    def test_circlecircum_with_max_radius(self):
        # Define a circle 'c3' with radius 1000 and check if 
        # it's circumference is 6283.19.
        c3= Circle(1000)
        self.assertEqual(c3.circumference(), 6283.19)
```